# Java socket.io wait for callback

Tags: java, asynchronous, android-asynctask, socket.io-java-client

My Activity code:

```
public String getValue(JSONObject data) {
    String value;
    socket.emit("request", data, new Ack() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            value = (String) args[1]; // how to wait for this value?
        });

    return value;
}
```

How do I wait for the `value` that came from the socket.io callback?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class  getvalue extends AsyncTask<JSONObject,Void,String>{


          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... jsonObjects) {
              String value;
              socket.emit("request", jsonObjects, new Ack() {
                  @Override
                  public void call(Object... args) {
                      value = (String) args[1]; // how to wait for this value?
                  }
          });
          return value;
      }
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
              //result is the final String;
          }
      }
```

And after that go to Activity that you want to use this function in and try this :

```
 getvalue a=new getvalue();
            getvalue.execute(data);
```

Here is some useful link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)
hopefully to work

Comment: thanks for the help but as you can see I need to wait for the socket emit callback which is asynchronous. So, it's not gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's still facing for the same issue, use CompletableFuture

```java
public String request(JSONObject... objects) {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    socket.emit("request", objects, (Ack) callback -> {
        future.complete(args[1].toString());
    });
    return future.join();
}
```

However, note that if answer wasn't provided, your code will be blocked until the answer would be provided by the server, however this is the question itself, so here you are